# How to enumerate all ActiveX elements with WMI?

Tags: javascript, windows, scripting, activex, wmi

Is it possible to enumerate all (or just enabled) ActiveX elements (*.dll, *.ocx) with WMI script?

Motivation: [ActiveXHelper](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/axhelper.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Scritomatic V2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=09dfc342-648b-4119-b7eb-783b0f7d1178&displaylang=en) tool have some sample like that :

`On Error Resume Next`

Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = &h20

arrComputers = Array("*")
For Each strComputer In arrComputers
   WScript.Echo
   WScript.Echo "=========================================="
   WScript.Echo "Computer: " & strComputer
   WScript.Echo "=========================================="

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
   Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ClassicCOMClass", "WQL", _
                                          wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

For Each objItem In colItems
      WScript.Echo "Caption: " & objItem.Caption
      WScript.Echo "ComponentId: " & objItem.ComponentId
      WScript.Echo "Description: " & objItem.Description
      WScript.Echo "InstallDate: " & WMIDateStringToDate(objItem.InstallDate)
      WScript.Echo "Name: " & objItem.Name
      WScript.Echo "Status: " & objItem.Status
      WScript.Echo
   Next
Next

Function WMIDateStringToDate(dtmDate)
WScript.Echo dtm: 
    WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(dtmDate, 5, 2) & "/" & _
    Mid(dtmDate, 7, 2) & "/" & Left(dtmDate, 4) _
    & " " & Mid (dtmDate, 9, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmDate, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmDate,13, 2))
End Function

Comment: As far as I can tell, Win32_ClassicCOMClass is not the class that lists activex objects. I cannot find my particular activex class or Flash, yet ActiveX helper finds it fine.